# Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver

Tags: ruby, macos, watir

In **irb** I do the following:

```
require "watir"
b = Watir::Browser.new :chrome
```

I then get the following error:

```
Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9515
```

OSX 10.12.3
Ruby 2.3.1
Chrome Driver latest version
Watir 6.2.0

Comment: you need to download the driver, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27719345/how-to-specify-the-location-of-the-chromedriver-binary

Comment: you can `gem install webdrivers` and it will automatically keep your system up to date with the latest version of any driver being used

Comment: We had to hand over the path to the chromedriver bin when using it on heroku. See my detailed answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/50781946/135160

Answer (score 10):

```
gem install webdrivers
```

Worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

Solved in a minute!

- Download geckodriver from [here](https://github.com/mozilla/geckodriver/releases/tag/v0.26.0)
- Extract the tar.gz file into your application root folder
- Give this command in terminal from application root path `export PATH=$PATH:/path/to/application`