# Ruby / Heroku Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9516

Tags: selenium, heroku, watir

I'm trying to run headless chrome on Heroku with ruby. I've installed the buildpacks https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome/ and https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver and have set the Selenium driver_path to the correct location (I've checked this as before setting the Selenium driver path I get `cannot find Chrome binary`, after setting it to the `GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN` variable set by the buildpack I get the `unable to connect to chromedriver`).

When I try to start Selenium / Watir with `Watir::Browser.new :chrome` or `Watir::Browser.new :chrome, headless:true` I get `Selenium::WebDriver::Error::WebDriverError: unable to connect to chromedriver 127.0.0.1:9516`

Any suggestions are appreciated

Comment: is chromedriver actually on the path?   can you just open up a terminal or command line prompt and run `chromedriver -v` and get a response?

Answer (score 4):

We also had the same problem due to the combination of configuration errors and passing the correct options hash to `Watir::Browser.new`. We are using `watir (6.10.3)`, `selenium-webdriver (~> 3.4, >= 3.4.1)` and `ruby '2.4.0'`.

To get everything working on Heroku we added the following buildpacks:

- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome
- https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver
- heroku/ruby

To successfully initialize the browser you need to pass the path to chromedriver bin within the options hash. heroku-buildpack-chromedriver provides an environment variable `GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM` for the bin search path. At the end the code which will work locally and on Heroku looks like this:

```
opts = {
    headless: true
}

if (chrome_bin = ENV.fetch('GOOGLE_CHROME_SHIM', nil))
  opts.merge!( options: {binary: chrome_bin})
end 

browser = Watir::Browser.new :chrome, opts
browser.goto "your url"
```

Answer (score 2):

If anyone else stumbles across this, there's a good example here: https://github.com/jormon/minimal-chrome-on-heroku